# Scroll always start on the top in ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I have an UITableView and all rows navigate to other UIView which include UIScrollView. Sometimes when I navigate it scroll start middle of the view, or bottom of the view. But I want everytime I scroll it, scroll must be on the top of the view. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you are using  `[self.scrViewHaberDetay setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];` in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, not in the viewDidLoad.  It will then work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods : `[_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f) animated:NO];`

Comment: this view does not include tableview... it's a UIScrollView so I try this:

    [self.scrViewHaberDetay setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f) animated:NO];

But it didn't work...

Comment: Maybe can you send us a video because personally I don't understand at all the behavior you want to have and which is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the UIView loaded, you can manually make it scroll to top, so it will always be start on top. [self.scroll scrollRectToVisible:rc animated:YES], rc is CGRect, you can make it rc.origin.x=0, rc.origin.y=0;

Comment: I try this and it didn't work;   
    
    CGRect cr;
    cr.origin.x = 0;
    cr.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrView scrollRectToVisible:cr animated:YES];

Comment: It is tricky...I used that for auto scroll with timer, so it can scroll from top to bottom automatically. check the docs then, there should be similar functions do the same thing.